# Problema ao realizar requisição GET

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, http-request, postman

Estou com um problema ao tentar realizar um GET em uma pagina da WEB e armazenar os dados em um banco de dados,

Ao fazer a requisição via POSTMAN retorna o erro Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3330

Meu codigo

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const mysql = require("mysql");

const app = express();

// MySQL connection Dados removidos por segurança
const connectionConfig = {
    host: "",
    port: "",
    user: "",
    password: "",
    database: "",
};

// API endpoint
app.get("/produtos", async (req, res) => {
  let productCode = request.body.data.retorno.estoques[0].estoque.codigo;
  // let productName = request.body.data.retorno.estoques[0].estoque.nome;
  let currentInventory =
    request.body.data.retorno.estoques[0].estoque.estoqueAtual;
  let balance =
    request.body.data.retorno.estoques[0].estoque.depositos[0].deposito.saldo;
  let virtualInventory =
    request.body.data.retorno.estoques[0].estoque.depositos[0].deposito
      .saldoVirtual;
  try {
    // Retrieve stock data from API
    const blingApiKey =
      "Aqui vai a chave da API";
    const url = `https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/produto/json/&apikey=${blingApiKey}`;
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const stockData = response.data["Global Quote"];

    // Connect to MySQL database
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection(connectionConfig);

    // Insert stock data into MySQL
    const sql =
      'INSERT INTO currentInventory (NULL, productCode, productName, currentInventory, balance, virtualInventory) VALUES (NULL, "' +
      blingProductId +
      '" , "' +
      productCode +
      '" , "' +
      currentInventory +
      '", "' +
      balance +
      '" , "' +
      virtualInventory +
      '", "';
    const params = [
      stockData["01. symbol"],
      stockData["05. price"],
      new Date(),
    ];
    const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute(sql, params);

    const blingUrl = `https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/produto/json/&apikey=${blingApiKey}`;
    const blingData = {
    };
    const blingResponse = await axios.post(blingUrl, blingData);

    res.json({ message: 'Stock data retrieved and integrated with Bling' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ message: "Error retrieving and integrating stock data" });
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: sua porta não é 3000, porque tá acessando com `127.0.0.1:3330`??

Answer (score -1):

Você está tentando acessar a porta 3330 pela URL (127.0.0.1:3330), mas está escutando o serviço na porta 3000. Corrija isso e tente novamente.